# Recalculating values with jQuery on orientation change not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have created the function in order to deal with some full screen sizing issues on mobile devices. It works very well however does not recalculate the value for height more than once (only calculated on load and not on orientation change). I added the alert to demonstrate that it is not running the calculation more than once. Any help here with allowing for the calculation of this value on each orientation change would be greatly appreciated.

jQuery: (Only runs on mobile devices or inspect mobile configuration)

```
function resizeBackground() {
    $(".header__container").removeAttr('style');
    var fixedHeight = $(window).height();
    var bg = $(".home-carousel, .flickity-viewport, .flickity-slider, .carousel-cell, .header__container, .site-header--drawer .nav-bar");
    var softScroll = $(".soft__scroll--container");
    var squiggle = $(".squiggle__container");
    var slideNumbers = $(".slide__numbers");

    bg.height(fixedHeight);
    softScroll.css('top', fixedHeight - 50 + "px");
    slideNumbers.css('top', fixedHeight - 140 + "px");
    squiggle.css('padding-top', 10 + "px");
    console.log(fixedHeight);
}

if(isMobile.any()) {
    $(window).on("load resize", function(event) {
        resizeBackground();
    });
}
```

Comment: Have you tried setting a breakpoint or using console.log() to verify that your code actually enters that IF block and registers the event listener? I'm not familiar with what isMobile.any() is or where it's defined so it's hard to tell if it's set up properly or behaving the way you expect.

Comment: @JoshLindoo I'll include that part in the edited question right now.

Comment: I think the issue is probably that isMobile.any() returns false. If I copy paste the function and the resize event listener code that you have here into the console for your site the function fires the way you would expect. Also, I'd recommend that you just remove the IF conditional from around the event listener instead of trying to create a function that tells you if the browser is "any browser". If you were trying to limit it to just those devices you listed then I think maybe you're using a device that isn't listed?

Comment: I have updated the quesiton to include the updated script which has implemented the solutions proposed by @AndreiGheorghiu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You expect `.header__container` to change height when `orientationchange`, `load` or `resize` fire on `$(window)`.
It *would*...  **if it didn't have a `height` set inside the `style` attribute**, applied by the previous run of `resizeBackground()` (from `bg.height(fixedHeight);`).

You need to remove this attribute first, to allow `.header__container` to resize and give you the correct, updated `.height()`.
Add this as the first line in `resizeBackground()` and it will work as intended:

```js
$(".header__container").removeAttr('style');
```

You can see the script working properly in this recording: https://youtu.be/z2spumFbuRs

---

Alternatively, you might want to define `fixedHeight` as:

```
var fixedHeight = $(window).height();
```

... which will be slightly less expensive, since it doesn't imply DOM manipulation and resizing before getting the header height (which happens to be `100vh` after `style` is removed).

---

One last thing: if you bind on `resize` there is no point in binding on `orientationchange`, as `orientationchange` cannot occur without a `resize`. Additionally, you might want to debounce calls to `resizeBackground()` and not allow it to run more than 20 times/second.

Comment: Thanks so much for this detailed and simple solution. I really appreciate the help, totally saved me on this one.

Answer (score 3):

**orientationchange timing**

> The timing of the `orientationchange` event with relation to the
>   change of the client `height` and `width` is different between
>   browsers, though the current implementation will give you the correct
>   value for `event.orientation` derived from `window.orientation`. This
>   means that if your bindings are dependent on the `height` and `width`
>   values you may want to disable `orientationChange` altogether with
>   `$.mobile.orientationChangeEnabled = false` to let the fallback
>   `resize` code trigger your bindings.

https://api.jquerymobile.com/orientationchange/

So you might stop listening to `orientationchange` or add a timeOut to your function.

The code below works fine (I've added Firefox user agent):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var isMobile = {
    Android: function() {
      return navigator.userAgent.match(/Firefox/i);
    },
    BlackBerry: function() {
      return navigator.userAgent.match(/BlackBerry/i);
    },
    iOS: function() {
      return navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone|iPad|iPod/i);
    },
    Opera: function() {
      return navigator.userAgent.match(/Opera Mini/i);
    },
    Windows: function() {
      return navigator.userAgent.match(/IEMobile/i);
    },
    any: function() {
      return (isMobile.Android() || isMobile.BlackBerry() || isMobile.iOS() || isMobile.Opera() || isMobile.Windows());
    }
  };

  function resizeBackground() {
    var fixedHeight = $(".header__container").height();
    var bg = $(".home-carousel, .flickity-viewport, .flickity-slider, .carousel-cell, .header__container, .site-header--drawer .nav-bar");
    var softScroll = $(".soft__scroll--container");
    var squiggle = $(".squiggle__container");
    var slideNumbers = $(".slide__numbers");

    bg.height(fixedHeight);
    softScroll.css('top', fixedHeight - 50 + "px");
    slideNumbers.css('top', fixedHeight - 140 + "px");
    squiggle.css('padding-top', 10 + "px");
    alert(fixedHeight);
  }

  if (isMobile.any()) {
    $(window).on("load resize", function(event) {
      resizeBackground();
    });
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Are you sure that your user agent matches?

Comment: Hey, thanks for taking a look at my code. Even if I remove the orientationchange listener and just leave load and resize, the function still does not work correctly.

Comment: I believe that is the same code that I provided, is it not? In any case it still isn't working for me unfortunately.

Comment: The height of the elements with "fixedHeight" by jQuery does not changer on orientation change and this can be demonstrated by the alert message staying constant value when changing orientations.

Comment: The page from your question does not contain any `alert`. The code I've tested works fine. Could you please make a jsfiddle or codepen or whatever snippet showing your problem?